# Spark Job Server No Such Process while starting the job server

Tags: spark-jobserver

I have issue while trying to start the job server. Im getting the below error,

```
./server_start.sh
./server_start.sh: line 41: kill: (113865) - No such process
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: can you see in the directory where you are starting this command a file called `spark-jobserver.pid` ? if yes, could you remove it and try again to start the server?

Comment: yes actually i tried that also, but same error i am getting. And one more thing i dont think this causes an issue. The spark submit command is not getting executed. can u please let me know the spark submit command that is included in the server_start.sh.

Comment: could you put the lines from 40 to 44 of the script `server_start.sh` that you are using to start the job server?

Comment: below are lines 38 to 49,
MAIN="spark.jobserver.JobServer"
PIDFILE=$appdir/spark-jobserver.pid
if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ] && kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
   echo 'Job server is already running'
   exit 1
fi

cmd='$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class $MAIN --driver-memory $JOBSERVER_MEMORY
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$LOGGING_OPTS"
  --driver-java-options "$GC_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_OPTS $CONFIG_OVERRIDES"
  $@ $appdir/spark-job-server.jar $conffile'

Comment: I could't unnderstand why kill -0 tries to send a signal to the process!!! as a workaround, could you just comment the lines 41 to 44 (by adding # before each line).  You should make sure that the server is not started

Comment: Yes i have commented it..i have so much confusion in starting the server..can u pls verify the below steps that i have done:  1. Deployed the job server from local to spark cluster 2. commented out the lines 41 to 44 in server_start. 3. Started the server using server_start.sh.. Can u please tell me the flow when it starts the server and submits the job

Comment: FYI it does nothing if i start the server after commenting out the lines

Comment: Are you trying to setup from master branch? If this is a dev setup, may be you could use docker.